# Unable to trigger Zephyr for Jira Server REST API

Tags: python, jira, jira-zephyr

I have Jira Server `7.10.1` and Zephyr for JIRA `3.6.4.36403917` running on my local linux server.

Now I'd like to use API to get the information in Zephyr related fields.

Here's the python code that I used to fetch the information in Jira Zephyr fields.

```
import config
import requests
import base64

auth = base64.b64encode(f"{config.username}:{config.password}".encode())
header = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + auth.decode(),
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
}

response = requests.get(f"{config.jira_url}/rest/zephyr/1.0/zchart/issueStatuses?projectId=13900", headers=header)
print(response)
```

I've checked that I can use `config.username` and `config.password` to login my Jira server.

And I've given permissions to `config.username` so that it can view the content of Jira project with project id = 13900.

However, when I run `print(response.status_code)`, I get `403`. Does anyone know why my python code doesn't work?

The value of `response.text` is `{}`. I can't get any further information from `response`.

I created the above code by referencing the document in `https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/zephyr/1.0/application.wadl`.

[This article](https://support.smartbear.com/zephyr-squad/faq/403-forbidden-error-while-using-zapi-api-s/) says that I should change `rest/zephyr/1.0` to `rest/zapi/1.0` to make the API work.

But after making this change, I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

Here's part of the error message:

```
2023-06-27 05:50:36,214 http-nio-8080-exec-242 ERROR      [o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[default]] Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.atlassian.logging.log4j.FilteredPatternLayout.formatStackTrace(FilteredPatternLayout.java:345)
        at com.atlassian.logging.log4j.FilteredPatternLayout.format(FilteredPatternLayout.java:330)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:310)
        at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
        at com.atlassian.jira.logging.JiraHomeAppender.doAppend(JiraHomeAppender.java:206)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.fatal(Category.java:382)
        at com.thed.zephyr.je.filter.ZAPIRestFilter.doFilter(ZAPIRestFilter.java:160)
        ... 12 filtered
        at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21)
        ... 53 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(JiraSecurityFilter.java:66)
        ... 1 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.doFilter(JiraSecurityFilter.java:64)
        ... 16 filtered
        at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:37)
        ... 19 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.doFilter(CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.java:30)
        ... 10 filtered
        at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21)
        ... 4 filtered
        at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.LocationCleanerFilter.doFilter(LocationCleanerFilter.java:36)
        ... 26 filtered
        at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.MetricsCollectorFilter.doFilter(MetricsCollectorFilter.java:25)
        ... 23 filtered
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```